# Работа с командной строкой в языке Си

Tags: c, строки, функции, командная-строка

Условие задачи следующее: в main(), используя ***командную строку***, ввести строку любых символов. В ***функции*** сформировать сумму всех цифр, содержащихся в переданной в неё строке. Результат вернуть в main() и вывести на экран.

---

Подскажите, что нужно исправить в коде - заранее спасибо (код приложен ниже).

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int sum(char* str)
{
    int sum = 0, i = 0;
    while (*(str + i))
    {
        if (*(str + i) > '0' && *(str + i) < '9')
        {
            sum += atoi(str + i) - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


int main(int count, char** s)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int i;
    int k;
    printf("Строка: \n");
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        puts(s[i]);
        k = sum(s[i]);
        printf("Сумма цифр - %d", k);
    }
}
```

---

Пример:

1. Строка, введённая в аргументы команды в отладке программы: 123hello456
2. То, что должна вывести функция подсчёта цифр в символьной строке: 21.

Comment: эээ.. А что выводит?

Comment: ничего не выводит, кроме самой строки - то есть суммы вообще нет

Comment: А Вы при запуске ей `count ` задаете? И зачем Вы входную строку так странно читаете? Почему не сразу всю?

Comment: а разве count не определяется автоматически? здесь он будет равен двум, потому что первый аргумент - путь к исполняемому файлу, а второй - сама строка - поправьте меня, если я неправ.

Comment: Честно говоря, крайне редко доводилось работать с параметрами командной строки. Сейчас запустил, посмотрел. Второй параметр - имя файла, а `count ==1`

Comment: И в самой функции `sum` цикл построен неверно. Пройдите его по шагам. На первой же цифре вы попадаете в вечный цикл. Кроме того ,что-то неверно с вычислением суммы.... на первом шаге (когда символ = `1`) сумма становится 75....

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно понимаете, что задают параметры функции *main()*. Прочитайте хотя бы тут: http://cppstudio.com/post/421/

А программа Ваша гораздо проще, чем Вы написали:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int count, char** s)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int i;
    int k, n;
    
    if (count != 2) {
       printf("Неверное количество аргументов в командной строке: %d\n", count);
       return -1;
    }
       
    printf("Строка: %s\n", s[1]);
    n = strlen(s[1]);
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[1][i]))
        k += s[1][i] - '0';
    }

    printf("Сумма цифр - %d\n", k);
}
```